# Multiple linear regression, multi-period data and p-values

Tags: panel-data, multiple-regression

I would like to better understand the limitations of the MLR in regards to multiperiod data.

Lets say I am looking at financial data for 10 companies, and each of those 10 companies has 5 periods worth of data, can I treat all 100 datapoints the same, or do I need to break it down into individual years?

Additionally, I am noticing that removing a factor will cause another factors p-value to sporadically rise by a large number. My impression of the way a MLR works is that each factor should be independent of the each other, and while the coefficient is supposed to be divided by p number of factors, its relating stats like p-value and t-stat should remain constant if the data for that factor doesn't change

Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 4):

This is called *panel data*. This is a huge topic.

The simplest answer would be that you can include all 100 observations in your regression, but you should have firm-specific and year-specific dummy variables.

I'm not sure what you mean by "factor," but, in general, removing predictors/independent variables from your model does change the other coefficients. This is related to the concept of *omitted variables bias*. The predictors are not independent of one another, so each impacts the others. Changing the variables in your model can change all the coefficients and standard errors, which, in turn, changes all the p-values.